# finding a list of objects based off of the logic from nested objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have coaches and I have teams and I have sponsors.

Coaches can have many teams. 
Teams can have many sponsors
Sponsors have 1 registration_method

I'm having trouble finding all of the coaches who do not have teams that have sponsors with a registration_method set to 'email' (I know....its gnarly)

My sudo code is:

> find all coaches with teams that have sponsors that don't have a registration method set to 'email'

I've tried horribly with psql here and had no luck so far.

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE (users.roles @> '{coach}')" 
AND WHERE (users.teams.sponsors.registration_method != '{email}')
```

My knowledge with SQL queries is weak (as you can likely tell) and i've been struggling. Would anybody have any ideas how to assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm totally guessing at your table structures, so if you can clarify that it would be a big help.  Notionally, assuming you have a users table, team, sponsors and registration methods, a query like this should yield all coaches who do not have at least one sponsor whose registration method is email:

```
select
  u.*
from
  users u
where
  u.role @> array['coach'] and
  not exists (
    select null
    from
      teams t
      join sponsors s on < whatever >
      join registration_methods r on < whatever >
    where
      u.user_id = t.coach_id and
      r.registration_method = 'email'
)
```

The key is the semi-join (`not exists`) which will yield everything that does not match the condition described.

If it's all one big table (with arrays) as your question hints, then that's a horse of a different color.